# Spring constructor-arg and property are not setting values

Tags: java, spring

I have a DrawingApp class which needs a Triangle object configured using spring.xml in spring.
constructor-arg and property are not setting the instance variables of triangle object.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        System.out.println(triangle);
    }

}
```

```
public class Triangle {
    
    private String type;
    private int height;
    public Triangle() {
    }
    public Triangle(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public Triangle(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public Triangle(String type, int height) {
        this.type = type;
        this.height = height;
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(getType() + " Triangle drawn of height " + getHeight());
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Height = " + height + " type = " + type;
    }
}
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"> 

    <bean id="triangle" class="com.spring.springDemoJavaBrains.Triangle">
        <!-- <property name="type" value="equilateral" /> -->
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="equilateral" />
        <constructor-arg type="int" value="20" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This the output I am receiving on running DrawingApp

> Height = 0 type = null

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using an obsolete mechanism of setting up Spring instead of using Spring Boot? (Note also that _data objects_ generally shouldn't be beans; lots data objects are created to represent the various actions happening. Beans are _service objects_.)

Comment: Hi @Lakshmi, I ran your code in Intellij Idea (using spring-context:5.3.9 as a maven dependcy) and it works correctly for me. Try refreshing/rebuilding the project, it's possible that the you changed your xml and your IDE didn't pick up the changes. I uploaded my test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qd1goeRe1223u0z7ISBBS1DOulXU20Ip/view?usp=sharing) and you can see a screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/zfTmDNw).